# set header authorization to angular $http post

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i want to set an authorization on the header of $http.post request in angular js.

on simple html ajax it works:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) { //do something 
  }
};
xhttp.open("POST", url, true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "xxxxxxxxxx");
xhttp.send();
```

On angular I get an error message - `"Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined"`

```
var configHeader = {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'xxxxxx'
  }
};

$http.post(url, configHeader).then(function(response) {
  //do something 
});
```

please help.

Comment: Did you add `$http` in your dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation

```
var configHeader = {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'xxxxxx'
  }
};

$http.post(url, {}, configHeader).then(function(response) {
  //do something 
});
```

Comment: Hi Rajith,  i have tried this and got the same error plus "xhttp is not defined".

Comment: what xhttp? the service name is $http

Comment: @Eliran Hi, xhttp is for the first one. You haven't defined the variable in the second case.

Comment: @Eliran where are you using `xhttp`?

Comment: I don't use xhttp. Anyway, I have tried to reproduce this error again and  didn't succeeded.

Comment: I don't use xhttp. Anyway, I have tried to reproduce this error again and  didn't succeeded. 
still i stay with the same error "Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined". 
this error occurs after i get response form the server (response.status is 200), what make me think that maybe there is a problem on the server side.  i am continue to investigate it.

Answer (score 0):

`$http.post` has 3 parameters:

- url
- data
- config (optional)

You're missing the data to post...

Comment: hi jacron, i have tried to add an empty data object but it also didnt work. i have got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Sample angular request:

```
var req = {
method: 'POST',
url: 'http://example.com',
headers: {
Content-Type': undefined
},
data: { test: 'test' }
}
```

I am guessing, your configHeader should be `configHeader: {'Authorization': 'xxx'}`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer!

There is some bug in chrome that create this error only when you using break point on the developer tool. I removed the break point and this error never appeared again on the console.

FYI - this is the error which has been displayed on the chrome console before I had removed the break point:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/othDj.png)